# Have any astronauts or cosmonauts died in space?

Tags: spaceflight

When I lived on the Space Coast I overheard gossip that one or more cosmonauts died in space.

Is there any truth to this?

I’m not asking about deaths from those disasters like Challenger, Columbia, or Apollo 1. I'm asking about death out in actual space.

Comment: It is not clear what area you asking. Death from natural causes like for example heart attack ? As far as I know, no such deaths are being recorded, because cosmonauts/astronauts are thoroughly  screened for their health.

Comment: It's pretty clear what he's asking.  At least to me.

Comment: Why not Columbia?

Comment: @edc65 The boundary of space, called the Karman line, is generally drawn at 100 km, although the USAF draws it at 50 mi (80 km). Columbia was destroyed on re-entry at about 60 km altitude, while Challenger was destroyed on ascent at 15 km and even the forward momentum of the cabin did not carry it higher than 20 km. Neither were in space by either definition.

Comment: @rs.29 I don't see why you think there would be a distinction. Has there been ANY death (natural or otherwise) beyond the border of space? Can't get any clearer than that.

Comment: @user32121 There is no mention of border of space in question, but there is a mention of disasters. What is "actual space" ?  We are all living in space. Question is unclear, should be rephrased.

Comment: @rs.29 it said space, which is a defined thing that doesn't need to be repeated. Actual space is anything above 100km from sea level. We live in an atmosphere, as opposed to space. This doesn't need to be repeated in the question since it is known and clear. It only mentioned disasters in the clear context of the Challenger, Columbia and Apollo 1 disasters. What is unclear?

Comment: Technically none since all where inside a capsule/vehicle and not "in space" however I suspect the broadly defined meaning may include those.

Comment: For whatever it may be worth, various altitudes of spaceflight death are summarized in Note #2 of https://what-if.xkcd.com/117/  If you're reading for numbers, click the "[2]", and if you're reading for humor, mouse over the pictures.

Comment: @user32121 Atmosphere is space with occasional nitrogen or oxygen molecule. Your definition of space is arbitrary. Is being on surface of Moon being in space ? Question is unclear, and should be edited, to at least include this arbitrary definition of space, if you want to preserve it.

Comment: @rs.29 The accepted answer clarifies the question.

Comment: @rs.29 Being on the surface of the moon would, in every sense of the word, be in space.

Comment: NASA = need another 7 astronauts.

Answer (score 100, accepted):

Yes, the three crew members of [Soyuz 11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soyuz_11): **Georgy Dobrovolsky**, **Vladislav Volkov**, and **Viktor Patsayev**.

On 29 June 1971, their spacecraft undocked from [Salyut 1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salyut_1), the first space station, to return to Earth. In the process, however, a breathing ventilation valve between the Soyuz's orbital and descent modules was accidentally loosened. This caused a fatal decompression at ~168km above earth's surface, quickly killing the crew.

According to a [NASA writeup](https://history.nasa.gov/SP-4209/ch8-2.htm) of the incident, the cabin pressure fell to zero for nearly 12 minutes, before increasing due to the ship re-entering the Earth's atmosphere. All three cosmonauts would have passed away within the first few minutes.

They remain the only humans known to have died in outer space (conventionally defined to begin at [100km above sea level](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K%C3%A1rm%C3%A1n_line)).

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/90102/discussion-on-answer-by-semaphore-have-any-astronauts-or-cosmonauts-died-in-spac).

Answer (score 23):

The only astronauts who have ever died in space are the crew of Soyuz 11:  Georgy Dobrovolsky, Vladislav Volkov, and Viktor Patsayev. This took place in 1971. Perhaps that you are thinking about the legend of the [lost cosmonauts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lost_Cosmonauts).

Comment: Hmmm. I'll admit I had heard a variant of that legend myself (and bought it. Silly me)